# How to remove an emergency alert?

Tags: android-10

I have a LG phone, android version 10. How do I remove a "Florida Blue Alert" from almost 2 weeks ago? I can't even see the actual message any more, just a web link, which doesn't work. As I recall, it showed a couple of views of some man, a fugitive, I think.
Typing the link into my laptop browser gets me a screen saying the alert has been cancelled and the situation resolved.
Swiping left and/or right gets me nothing.

Thanks!
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to restart the phone. Did this to verfy time change, and the alert vanished

Answer (score 0):

Go to Messages > click the three dotted menu in the top tight corner > Settings > Advanced > Wireless emergency alerts.

You should now see a list of alerts you have received and you should be able to remove them either individually or all at once via the three dotted menu in the top right corner.

Comment: Under Settings, I don't have an Advanced to click on. Nothing for wireless alerts.

Comment: @FlaStorm32 Then I'm out of ideas.